# How to make a Select2 Auto Complete work inside foreach binding of knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I am trying to use Autocomplete of select2 (Loading Remote Data) inside a table containing rows built using knockout foreach binding. The control does not work. It appears to be freezed, while I type in nothing seems to happen.
Also, I can't find any error in console in developer toolbar.

I have tried to place the control outside the foreach binding and it works perfectly.

I did found that I can make it work using a custom knockout binding, integration of knockout & Select2, I used code at link https://github.com/select2/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration and it worked.

In my original code, I had not used the custom select2 knockout binding and had instead activated select2 from js file. So my HTML was like following

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

and JS

```
$(".form-control").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        //The url we will send our get request to
        url: dataUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        //Our search term and what page we are on
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                pageSize: pageSize,
                pageNum: page,
                limit: -1,
                term: term,
             };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * pageSize) < data.Total;
            return { results: data.Results, more: more };
        }
    }
});
```

The example that worked has following html, **including the custom binding select2** which worked correctly.

```
<pre><select data-bind="options: $parent.clusters, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: ' ', select2: { placeholder: ' ', allowClear: true }" style="width: 220px"></select></pre>
```

I want to know following information

1. How can I make the select2 AutoComplete work inside the knockout foreach where I do **not** intend to define any custom binding like **select2** in html page.
2. How to make sure that foreach binding works correctly with the select2 control, I assume that we need to tell select2 how it should interpret the foreach binding or vice versa.

Comment: well if auto-complete is not working if you keep inside a foreach that say's `$(".form-control").select2` is not recognized because the elements under foreach are created after DOM creation . best alternative is use jqAuto plugin which works like a charm else you should try using delegates(register events) . cheers

Comment: Thanks, Could you describe more about delegates(register events), do you mean registering event handler on change in Select2 ?

Answer (score 0):

As per super cool's comment, you can modify your control like so in case you think of using jqAuto plugin.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: valueToBindWith, valueUpdate: 'input', jqAuto: { autoFocus: true, delay: 300 }, jqAutoSource: $root.valuescollection, jqAutoQuery: $root.searchValues, jqAutoValue: valueToBindWith, jqAutoSourceLabel: 'text', jqAutoSourceInputValue: 'text', jqAutoSourceValue: 'text'/>
```

Make sure to change $root to $parent as the case may be.